# Using gdalwarp and gdal_translate to create a KMLSUPEROVERLAY with a trasparent background from a GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, kmz

I attempting to create a KMZ file with an image overlay that has a transparent background. I'm using a GeoTIFF exported from the CoastWatch Utility Link to TIFF file:https://drive.google.com/file/d/13GcFkfU4GBz5WE6g9DJHerJjpZvgC0-I/view?usp=sharing
These are the commands I have been working with:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata 0 test.tif output.tif
gdalwarp -srcnodata 0,0,0 -dstalpha test.tif test_alpha.tif
gdal_translate.exe -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY test.tif test5.kmz -co format=jpeg -expand=rgba
```

So far I haven't been able to get the black areas to become transparent. I know it's possible because if I import the GeoTIFF into Google Earth it displays properly with a transparent background.

Gdalinfo from test.tif:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: test.tif
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-81.048056943385745,29.889615700862493)
Pixel Size = (0.002144920181308,-0.002144920181308)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_ARTIST=BigTV
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2020:05:14 14:55:22
  TIFFTAG_HOSTCOMPUTER=Java 12.0.1 on Windows 10 10.0 amd64
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=Kd_490 = color_index*0.0011372549019607841 + 0.010000000000000002
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=[cwutils 3.5.1.762 20191112_223457] cwrender --format=tif --enhance=Kd_490 --function=linear --range=0.01/0.3 --palette=Rainbow2 1.hdf 0.TIF
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -81.0480569,  29.8896157) ( 81d 2'53.00"W, 29d53'22.62"N)
Lower Left  ( -81.0480569,  28.7914166) ( 81d 2'53.00"W, 28d47'29.10"N)
Upper Right ( -79.9498578,  29.8896157) ( 79d56'59.49"W, 29d53'22.62"N)
Lower Right ( -79.9498578,  28.7914166) ( 79d56'59.49"W, 28d47'29.10"N)
Center      ( -80.4989574,  29.3405161) ( 80d29'56.25"W, 29d20'25.86"N)
Band 1 Block=512x16 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Color Table (RGB with 256 entries)
    0: 124,0,255,255
    1: 124,0,255,255
    2: 120,0,255,255
    3: 115,0,255,255
    4: 111,0,255,255
    5: 106,0,255,255
    6: 102,0,255,255
    7: 97,0,255,255
    8: 93,0,255,255
    9: 88,0,255,255
   10: 84,0,255,255
   11: 79,0,255,255
   12: 75,0,255,255
   13: 70,0,255,255
   14: 66,0,255,255
   15: 61,0,255,255
   16: 57,0,255,255
   17: 52,0,255,255
   18: 48,0,255,255
   19: 43,0,255,255
   20: 39,0,255,255
   21: 34,0,255,255
   22: 30,0,255,255
   23: 25,0,255,255
   24: 21,0,255,255
   25: 16,0,255,255
   26: 12,0,255,255
   27: 7,0,255,255
   28: 3,0,255,255
   29: 0,2,255,255
   30: 0,6,255,255
   31: 0,11,255,255
   32: 0,15,255,255
   33: 0,20,255,255
   34: 0,24,255,255
   35: 0,29,255,255
   36: 0,33,255,255
   37: 0,38,255,255
   38: 0,42,255,255
   39: 0,47,255,255
   40: 0,51,255,255
   41: 0,56,255,255
   42: 0,60,255,255
   43: 0,65,255,255
   44: 0,69,255,255
   45: 0,74,255,255
   46: 0,78,255,255
   47: 0,83,255,255
   48: 0,87,255,255
   49: 0,92,255,255
   50: 0,96,255,255
   51: 0,101,255,255
   52: 0,105,255,255
   53: 0,110,255,255
   54: 0,114,255,255
   55: 0,119,255,255
   56: 0,123,255,255
   57: 0,128,255,255
   58: 0,132,255,255
   59: 0,137,255,255
   60: 0,141,255,255
   61: 0,146,255,255
   62: 0,150,255,255
   63: 0,155,255,255
   64: 0,159,255,255
   65: 0,164,255,255
   66: 0,168,255,255
   67: 0,173,255,255
   68: 0,177,255,255
   69: 0,182,255,255
   70: 0,186,255,255
   71: 0,191,255,255
   72: 0,195,255,255
   73: 0,200,255,255
   74: 0,204,255,255
   75: 0,209,255,255
   76: 0,213,255,255
   77: 0,218,255,255
   78: 0,222,255,255
   79: 0,227,255,255
   80: 0,231,255,255
   81: 0,236,255,255
   82: 0,241,255,255
   83: 0,245,255,255
   84: 0,250,255,255
   85: 0,254,255,255
   86: 0,255,251,255
   87: 0,255,247,255
   88: 0,255,242,255
   89: 0,255,238,255
   90: 0,255,233,255
   91: 0,255,229,255
   92: 0,255,224,255
   93: 0,255,220,255
   94: 0,255,215,255
   95: 0,255,211,255
   96: 0,255,206,255
   97: 0,255,202,255
   98: 0,255,197,255
   99: 0,255,193,255
  100: 0,255,188,255
  101: 0,255,184,255
  102: 0,255,179,255
  103: 0,255,175,255
  104: 0,255,170,255
  105: 0,255,166,255
  106: 0,255,161,255
  107: 0,255,157,255
  108: 0,255,152,255
  109: 0,255,148,255
  110: 0,255,143,255
  111: 0,255,139,255
  112: 0,255,134,255
  113: 0,255,130,255
  114: 0,255,125,255
  115: 0,255,121,255
  116: 0,255,116,255
  117: 0,255,112,255
  118: 0,255,107,255
  119: 0,255,103,255
  120: 0,255,98,255
  121: 0,255,94,255
  122: 0,255,89,255
  123: 0,255,85,255
  124: 0,255,80,255
  125: 0,255,76,255
  126: 0,255,71,255
  127: 0,255,67,255
  128: 0,255,58,255
  129: 0,255,53,255
  130: 0,255,49,255
  131: 0,255,44,255
  132: 0,255,40,255
```

Comment: You may want to use png as the output format: -co format=png
That worked perfectly for me. jpeg doesn't support transparency